# How to "override pkg-config" by setting MYLIB_LIBS and MYLIB_CFLAGS?

Tags: build, configure, pkg-config

I'm trying to build some program which uses GNU autotools on a Unix-like OS. It needs some library which my OS distribution doesn't have, say `mylib`, so I download, build and install that library under `/opt/mylib`.

Now, I want to tell the configure script to use `mylib` under `/opt/mylib`, but it doesn't have a command-line option such as `--mylib-location=`. However, `configure --help` tells me:

```
Some influential environment variables:
... snip ...
  MYLIB_CFLAGS C compiler flags for mylib, overriding pkg-config
  MYLIB_LIBS   linker flags for mylib, overriding pkg-config
... snip ...
```

I'm guessing these are shell variables I need to set. But - what exactly do I need to set them to?

Answer (score 1):

These variables are expanded in the command-line for compilation and for linking respectively. So, typically, the `_CFLAGS` would need to indicate an include file search path and `_LIBS` would need to tell the linker to use the library, plus indicate a search path for it.

In your specific case, and assuming typical layout of `/opt/mylibs`, you need to set:

```
MYLIB_CFLAGS=-I/opt/mylib/include
MYLIB_LIBS="-L/opt/mylib/lib -lmylib"
```

and that should do it. The text about "overriding pkg-config" is due to how `pkg-config` is used as the default for obtaining these flags. Example (for the PNG library and on my system):

```
# pkg-config --cflags libpng
-I/usr/include/libpng16
# pkg-config --libs libpng
-lpng16 -lz
```

pkg-config has search paths configured for include and library directories, plus a repository of `.pc` files etc., with which it determines the system location of various libraries/packages.